# KDE: temporarily changing sound system

Tags: debian, kde, audio, pulseaudio

A little time ago, I reported a bug related to Phonon/pulseaudio. For debugging purposes I was told to disable pulseaudio so phonon can use the hardware directly.

So I searched about how to disable pulseaudio on KDE, but only found solutions in the form `apt-get purge pulseaudio*`, but since I'm not planning on disabling pulseaudio permanently I do not appreciate that solution.

Is there any way to tell Phonon (or the VLC backend I'm using) not to use pulseaudio?

My system:

OS: Debian jessie
Graphical interface: KDE
Phonon backend: VLC

Answer (score 0):

Just kill it. From `man pulseaudio`:

```
   -k | --kill
          Kill  an  already  running PulseAudio daemon of the calling user
          (Equivalent to sending a SIGTERM).
```

So, simply open a terminal and run `pulseaudio -k`.

Comment: If i do this pulseaudio is just restarted.

Comment: @IchUndNichtDu that stops the current `pulseaudio` process. Of course you have no sound, that's because your system is configured to use `pulseaudio`. You asked how you can temporarily disable pulseaudio, that's what you did. It might be started again automatically after a few seconds (depends on what programs you have running) that's probably why you see it in pstree.

Comment: No, my final question was `Is there any way to tell Phonon (or the VLC backend I'm using) not to use pulseaudio?`, not just to kill pulseaudio and break my sound until it is restarted. Sorry, if the title is misleading.

Comment: @IchUndNichtDu ah, I see. OK, I edited your question's title tomake that clearer.